# controller echo tabel with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, controller

How do I echo all records from the controller with a Ajax request? When I changed the code, I get only one name. So I made an array of the query. Unfortunately all Google answers didn't help.

My next step is also echo the score of the naam -> how can I echo naam and score in line?

Thanks for your help.

Controller code:

```
public function score(Request $request)
{
    $scores = DB::table('scores')->where('gameround_id', $gameround_id)->value('naam');
    $data = array();

 foreach ($scores as $score) {
   $data[] = $score->naam;
}

   return response()->json(['data'=> $data]); 
}
```

Ajax code:

```
   setInterval(function(){ 
   var gameround_id = '12';
   let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:"/ajaxRequestscore",
      data:{_token: _token, gameround_id: gameround_id},
      success:function(data){
        var html = '';
        data['data'].forEach(function(naam) {
            html += '<div>' + naam + '</div>'
        });
        $('#results').html(html);
      }
   });


  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get data and return it as json:
**Controller:**

```
public function score(Request $request)
{
    $data['scores'] = DB::table('scores')->where('gameround_id', $request->gameround_id)->get();
    
   return response()->json($data); 
}
```

**View:**
Using JS and ajax send requests and then retrieve and append data to the view.

```
<div id="scores"> </div>          
        
         <script>                 
            function mainTable() {
               var gameroundID = '12';
              $.ajax({
                    url: "{{url('/api/fetch-scores')}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                    gameround_id: gameroundID,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',                 
                    success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result.scores, function (key, value) {
                    $("#scores").append('<p> Naam: ' + value.naam + '</p><p>Score: ' + value.score + '</p>'); 
                   });
                 }
              });
            }            
        </script>
```

**Update results every 5000 miliseconds:**

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
$("#scores").html('');
mainTable();
     }, 5000);
</script>
```

**Route(web.php):**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\NaamController;
Route::post('api/fetch-scores', [NaamController::class, 'score']);
```

Comment: Shabab, do you also know how the scores update each 1000 miliseconds instead of add the results?

Comment: Sorry, I was out of city for awhile. Your problem solved or you are searching for a solution for refreshing table every 1000 miliseconds?

Comment: No problem of course! Problem nearly solved, I'm already very happy. It would be superb when I can refresh the table every 5000 seconds (I've changed 1000 -> 5000). The .append is add all the new data, is there also a javascript function who add and delete the earlier data?

Comment: Check auto refresh please. A little change in first JS function has been made too.